# ActiveX Image Box using double click to load image returns RunTime Error 53 if no picture is selected

Tags: vba, image, runtime-error, activex

I have a spreadsheet with 4 ActiveX Image boxes with some code that opens a file window if you double click on the box to load a picture into it but if you double click on the box but then choose not to add a photo and hit cancel it returns RunTime Error: 53. Is there something simple I can add to my code so that if you cancel out it doesn't cause an error? Code below.

```
 Private Sub Image1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
     Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Application.GetOpenFilename)
 End Sub

 Private Sub Image2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
     Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(Application.GetOpenFilename)
 End Sub

 Private Sub Image3_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
     Image3.Picture = LoadPicture(Application.GetOpenFilename)
 End Sub

 Private Sub Image4_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
     Image4.Picture = LoadPicture(Application.GetOpenFilename)
 End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The answer is in the question: "Is there something simple I can add to my code so that **if** you cancel out it doesn't cause an error?" - you can't just blindly pass `Application.GetOpenFilename` to `LoadPicture`, you need to make that *conditional* to the dialog not being cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

Make a little function that returns `Empty` if no picture is selected:

```
Private Function GetUserSelectedPicture() As Variant
    Dim path As Variant
    path = Application.GetOpenFilename 'returns a Boolean if cancelled
    If VarType(path) <> vbBoolean Then
        GetUserSelectedPicture = LoadPicture(path)
    End If
End Function
```

Then update your handlers to invoke it:

```
Image1.Picture = GetUserSelectedPicture
```

Note that it will fail to load certain image formats, such as .png.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Mathieu. Now I'm getting RunTime Error 424?

Comment: @Peter sorry, not sure how that happened - forgot the `Set` keyword there.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you but I'm still getting the same 424 RunTime error even with the set added.

Comment: My bad, OLE picture isn't an object apparently. A variant should work (remove the Set keywords). Also note that you can only load .gif,.jpg, or .bmp image formats.